# invoke iPad native "camera" app from website

Tags: ios, ipad, web, camera

Maybe anyone can help!? It is possible to "tap" a phone number on a website and that "Tap" invokes the smartphone's phone application and calls the number tapped on on the website. No need to remember or copy/paste to call that number, very user friendly.

I wonder, is it also possible to have a similar button on a website which when tapped invokes the iPads native "camera" app so that a user can take a photo with that app without having to close the browser and manually look for/open the camera app?

Interesting to hear!

Comment: Do you mean "tap" instead of "tab"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the telephone link: You can put a link on a website starting with `tel:`. Example:

```
<a href="tel:+15551234">Call</a>
```

More in the [Apple documentation for iPhone URL Schemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH6-SW1)

Regarding the camera: If you are viewing a website in a `UIWebView` in your own app, follow what @matt wrote.

And thanks to @Caleb: See the linked answer for accessing the camera in Safari.

In general, Apple provides a documentation for what you can do with a regular link at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html.

Comment: You *can* present the camera interface directly in Safari -- check the suggested duplicate.

Comment: Now that you mention it.. I remember taking a photo within the browser lately. Thank you! I'll edit my answer.